# How do I pass a templated service into a class without including that service's header file in that class header?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, variadic-templates, forward-declaration

I have a templated class for input events which is included in the application core.  I want to pass object from the core to another class without including the service's header in the class's header file.

First, is this even possible?  I know I can easily do it with a non-templated class using a forward declare, but in this case I don't think that will work.

Also, due to how the class works with identifying events using templates, it can't be abstracted into a base class.

I have been considering just passing a void pointer in and just casting it in the .cpp to what it should be but that removes any safety from it.

On the outside, the template looks like this:

```cpp
#include "events.h"

enum class intput_events {
    toggle_overlay,
    toggle_console,
    events_count
};

template <intput_events E, typename Listener>
using event = event_t<intput_events, E, Listener>;

using InputEventListener = event_listener<intput_events,
    event<intput_events::toggle_overlay, void(int)>,
    event<intput_events::toggle_console, void(int)>>;
```

Where function signatures are written into the template parameters with the matching enum.

I'm not sure if what I want to do here is possible or if I'm insane for how it's set up in the first place and trying to get this to work the way I want to isn't going to work out.

It may be that I just have to deal with it and put the include in.  I figured I'd ask first and I would appreciate any help or insight.

Comment: Anything can be trivially abstracted into a base class. `struct InputEventListener : event_listener<blah> {};`

Comment: You mention "service's header". What is a "service" here, and how does it enter the picture? What do you want to pass to what else?

Comment: n.m. answered it fast and I feel silly that I missed something which was that easy.

Comment: The service is an existing event system pointer being given to a new window class by the application core.  Might not be ideal but for the moment that's what the setup is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what @n.m. wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565950/how-do-i-pass-a-templated-service-into-a-class-without-including-that-services#comment97831234_55565950) I'm a goof for not trying to just abstract it directly.

```cpp
using InputEventListener = event_listener<intput_events,
    event<intput_events::toggle_overlay, void(int)>,
    event<intput_events::toggle_console, void(int)>>;
```

should actually be:

```cpp
class InputEventListener : public event_listener<intput_events,
    event<intput_events::toggle_overlay, void()>,
    event<intput_events::toggle_console, void(int)>> {};
```

Which would easily allow it to be forward declared.